# Why my particle system only shows particles falling down?

Tags: mesh, particles, physics, random, particle-nodes

I just started learning to use Blender and I'm following a tutorial in which i have to create a particle system over a mesh; but when I add the particle system and press play, it only shows the particles falling down. I've changed the Number, Seed, the "Emit from" option, the distribution, the scale, "Render as halo" and the physics but nothing seems to work. I even tried with another mesh but still doesnt work.
Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong please. I cant figure out if its the mesh or some of the particle system configuration or any other thing :(
Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Hello, Halo won't be rendered, but please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: If your problem is that the particles only emit from the origin... do you have any _Boolean_ or other modifiers on the objects? This looks like a duplicate of this question: [Particles emit from origin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300012/particles-emit-from-origin-when-boolean-intersect-or-difference-results-in-no-fa/300032#300032), see my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Your value of *Gravity* is 1 so adjust your *Gravity* value in *Field Properties* and check the result.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot the problem is less the gravity and the falling itself, but more that the particles just spawn from a single point although the outline shows a larger object.